# translate (change location) in object more or edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode, data-blocks, object-mode

What is the difference between translating (i.e moving an object) in object mode and achieving the same thing by selecting *all mesh elements* in *edit mode* and then moving those?

Why would one chose between the two methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In object mode, the object origin (the pink dot) moves as well. In edit mode, it doesn't.

The point is that if you want the origin to stay in a certain place, you could move all the elements in edit mode without affecting object origin location.

[image]

Comment: What's the significance of moving the origin?